# how to get the value from array which includes some value with lodash angular 4

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, lodash

hey i have this array

```
[
 0: "Migration, MD"
 1: "Lution, MD"
 2: "Mover, MD"
 3: "Dee"
 4: "Prov10A"
]
```

how to get the value which has the word MD in it
like which has MD it should give me something like this

```
[
 0: "Migration, MD"
 1: "Lution, MD"
 2: "Mover, MD"
]
```

how can i do that with lodash?
thanks

Comment: By *word MD* do you mean that you only want to match items that contain the string `MD` separated by word boundaries (spaces, punctuation marks, etc.) ?

Comment: which contains string MD just

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `filter` and `includes`:

```js
const arr = ["Migration, MD", "Lution, MD", "Mover, MD", "Dee", "Prov10A"];
const res = arr.filter(e => e.includes("MD"));
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Comment: This is good although if there was a value that contained "MD" not as a separate title but as part of the name it would also treat is as MD.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter`, `toLowerCase` & `includes`. `filter` will return a new array, `toLowerCase` will convert the case of the element so both `md` ,`MD` will be considered.

```js
let k = ["Migration", "MD", "Lution, MD", "Mover, MD", "Dee", "Prov10A"].filter(function(item) {

  return item.toLowerCase().includes('md')
});
console.log(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try the filter function

```
    const  arr = [
     "Migration, MD", "Lution, MD" , "Mover, MD", "Dee", "Prov10A"
    ]

    const out  = arr.filter(e => e.includes('MD'))
    console.log(out)
```

Comment: same as first comment it solved my problem but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find only one word with "MD" or only the first one, you can use java script find method, and if you want an array of words having "MD" then you can use filter method.

```js
 const  arr = [
     "Migration, MD", "Lution, MD" , "Mover, MD", "Dee", "Prov10A"
    ]
    const result = arr.find(word=>word.includes("MD"));
    console.log(result);
// to get array of words with MD simply change .find as .filter in above code.
```